# Are these two jQuery lines equivalent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, closures

I'm curious if the following two code samples **are equivalent** as far as performance is concerned:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      var $logo = $("h1.logo");
      $logo.on("mouseenter", function() {
        // Something
      });
}
```

Vs

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $("h1.logo").on("mouseenter", function() {
        // Something
      });
}
```

To be more precise, will jQuery implicitly covert `$("h1.logo")` into a variable or will it initialize a new jQuery object on every mouseenter event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("h1.logo")` will return a reference to an object.

The first version of your code will store that object in a variable called `$logo`.

The `on` method will be called on that object in both cases.

Nothing else (in that code) will ever touch the variable.

I don't know the jQuery internals very well, but as far as I know, a mouseenter event will neither reuse the original jQuery object or create a new one. (The value of `this` inside the function will be a DOM Element object, not a jQuery object).

Whatever happens when the `mouseenter` event fires, `$logo` won't be touched as it isn't referenced inside the event handler function.

**If** the object is reused, then it will be from another reference to it (i.e. not the reference copied into the `$logo` variable).

So the second version of the code is marginally more efficient as it doesn't spent time storing a value in a variable and then only using that value once. That might be optimised away by the JavaScript compiler. Either way, it is such a marginal change that it isn't worth thinking about from an efficiently point of view.

Optimise for readability and maintenance first.

When you worry about speed, use a profiler and find out where your code is really slow instead of worrying about trivial stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are equivalent. It is actually more efficient to use `var $logo = $("h1.logo");` if you are going to use the same selector in your code again. Instead of searching in the DOM again, your code will know where your selector is.

For Example,

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
         $('h1.logo').addClass('clicked');
         var html = $('h1.logo')[0].html();
         $('h1.logo').on("mouseenter", function() {
            // Something
         });
     }
```

If you're going to `logo` element again and again, it's better to cache the selector like below, that way you won't create a `new` jQuery object every time you need to call a method.

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
          var $logo = $(".logo");
          $logo.addClass('clicked');
          var html = $logo[0].html();
          $logo.on("mouseenter", function() {
            // Something
          });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the approaches are same. First option would be recommended, if you want to do some more operations on same jquery element (i.e $("h1.logo")). In that case the local reference copy would be used. Now considering this example, both are same, in second option `$("h1.logo")` returns an instance of jquery element, same as first approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, That the same. You are only placing a jquery object in a variable. for the $, some people prefer to put a dollar sign together with the variable to make a distinction between regular vars and jQuery objects.

Answer (score 0):

First off, as stated in previous answers, if you're going to use the element again, definitely assign it once to a local var. Assigning a single var is relatively negligible, so I wouldn't worry about it. Keep your code readable above all!

The answer to your question would depend on the interpreter and not on jQuery. V8 runs a lot of optimizations on code and I'm guessing this would be one of them but this would require looking into it...

If you want to test performance on a variety of interpreters, just test it with http://jsperf.com/ :)